# Access /etc/network/interfaces by inserting the HDD in another PC

Tags: ubuntu, networking, headless

I disabled the wrong network interface in the /etc/network/interfaces file on my headless Ubuntu PC. Now I can't ssh into it. I'd need to edit the file again and I don't have a display for that machine right now.

Can I just insert the HDD into another Ubuntu machine and edit the file? I know that I can't boot from that HDD but can I access all the files on it? If yes, do I get into permission troubles once I put the HDD back in the original machine?

Comment: Yes you can. Just attach the HHD to the other machine, and you shouldn't get permission errors. You are on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put the HDD on a different PC, without problems caused by permissions, as kindly noted above by [ARG](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/137575/arg).

If you have local access to the machine in question, you may also boot from a LiveUSB without removing the HDD from the target PC; most LiveUSBs have all the editing tools required. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 shows how.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I edit the network/inerfaces file with a Live USB Ubuntu? Doens't make sense to me if I just have access of the HDD and no Display etc.

Comment: Sorry, did not realize the PC in question was headless. LiveUSB is not a solution for headless machines. Have added the headless tag to your question to head off other well meaning folks.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose from the following options (the higher the number, the more difficult):

1. Take the HDD out of the existing machine, plug it into a USB enclosure and plug it into another PC preferably running Ubuntu, then Linux, then FreeBSD, ...
2. Booting from said HDD it in an `identical` machine is also no issue.
3. Inserting it in a Windows machine is possible but more difficult as you need [Parragon](https://www.paragon-drivers.com/en/lfswin/)  commercial software.
4. Booting it on another machine with wildly different hardware *could work* but might also get you into a lot of trouble.